# Saving the position of an dragged element

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

i'm, creating a feature for my drag and drop plugin to save the last dropped position.

Description: When someone pickes up an draggable element and then drags it around and then drops it. Cookies will save that location of the draggable element.

I started on creating a code. An example of what I want:

```
if (o.cookies === true) {
                $(oj).mouseup(function() {
                    var currentPos = $(this).position();
                    $.cookie('tposition' + $(this).index(), currentPos.top);
                    $.cookie('lposition' + $(this).index(), currentPos.left);
                });
                $(function() {
                    $(oj).each(function() {
                        var savedLeftPosition = $.cookie('lposition' + $(this).index());
                        var savedTopPosition = $.cookie('tposition' + $(this).index());
                        $(oj).css({
                            top: savedTopPosition,
                            left: savedLeftPosition
                        });
                    });
                });
            }
```

About the Code: That if is just something extra it just makes the cookies work if in the array `cookies` has the value `true`. The `var`, `oj` just stands for `this`. Well to be more clear `oj` is `'#drag'` because thats the element i'm trying to drag.

You can see an example of my whole code here: http://jsfiddle.net/shawn31313/kZxvd/3/
I'm using the following plugin for the cookies: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/cookie
The Cookie plugins code is [here](http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery.cookie.js__1.txt).

Hope someone with the information given. Good Luck, and Thanks in advance.